# n-largest elements in a sequence (need to retain duplicates)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, heap, sequence

I need to find the n largest elements in a list of tuples. Here is an example for top 3 elements.

```
# I have a list of tuples of the form (category-1, category-2, value)
# For each category-1, ***values are already sorted descending by default***
# The list can potentially be approximately a million elements long.
lot = [('a', 'x1', 10), ('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9), 
       ('a', 'x4',  8), ('a', 'x5', 8), ('a', 'x6', 7),
       ('b', 'x1', 10), ('b', 'x2', 9), ('b', 'x3', 8), 
       ('b', 'x4',  7), ('b', 'x5', 6), ('b', 'x6', 5)]

# This is what I need. 
# A list of tuple with top-3 largest values for each category-1
ans = [('a', 'x1', 10), ('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9), 
       ('a', 'x4', 8), ('a', 'x5', 8),
       ('b', 'x1', 10), ('b', 'x2', 9), ('b', 'x3', 8)]
```

I tried using `heapq.nlargest`. However it only returns the first 3 largest elements and doesn't return duplicates. For example,

```
heapq.nlargest(3, [10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6])
# returns
[10, 10, 10]
# I need
[10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8]
```

I can only think of a brute force approach. This is what I have and it works.

```
res, prev_t, count = [lot[0]], lot[0], 1
for t in lot[1:]:
    if t[0] == prev_t[0]:
        count = count + 1 if t[2] != prev_t[2] else count
        if count <= 3:
            res.append(t)   
    else:
        count = 1
        res.append(t)
    prev_t = t

print res
```

Any other ideas on how I can implement this?

EDIT: `timeit` results for a list of 1 million elements show that [mhyfritz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669632/n-largest-elements-in-an-sequence-need-to-retain-duplicates/6670141#6670141) runs in 1/3rd the time of brute force. Didn't want to make the question too long. So added more details in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669632/n-largest-elements-in-an-sequence-need-to-retain-duplicates/6671383#6671383).

Comment: @Toader Mihai Claudiu is right. One optimization you could try is to split all the keys into different lists and get out of the loop after picking the first three from each list. This way you won't have to loop over the entire list. (This is assuming you haven't spent time sorting in the first place. In the absence of the sorting constraint, the heap solutions should work best)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it from your code snippet that `lot` is grouped w.r.t. *category-1*. Following should work then:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

ans = []
for x, g1 in groupby(lot, itemgetter(0)):
    for y, g2 in islice(groupby(g1, itemgetter(2)), 0, 3):
        ans.extend(list(g2))

print ans
# [('a', 'x1', 10), ('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9), ('a', 'x4', 8), ('a', 'x5', 8),
#  ('b', 'x1', 10), ('b', 'x2', 9), ('b', 'x3', 8)]
```

Comment: And the one liner:  
`list(chain(*(list(g2) for x, g1 in groupby(lot, itemgetter(0)) for y, g2 in islice(groupby(g1, itemgetter(2)), 0, 3))))`

Comment: The combination of `islice` and `groupby` in the second loop is just brilliant! Thanks for a great solution!

Comment: Yep. This just looks beautiful :)

Comment: Major caveat: The code will break in the future if the order of the input ever changes.

Comment: @Praveen Gollakota: Glad I could help. Also, thanks for providing the additional details (`timeit` comparison, trace).

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the input data sorted that way then is very probably that your solution is a little better than the heapq based one.

Your algorithm complexity is O(n) while the heapq based one is conceptually O(n * log(3)) and it will probably need more passes over the data to arrange it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional details ... I timed both [mhyfritz's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669632/n-largest-elements-in-an-sequence-need-to-retain-duplicates/6670141#6670141) that uses `itertools` and  and my code (brute-force).

Here are the `timeit` results for `n = 10` and for a list with 1 million elements.

```
# Here's how I built the sample list of 1 million entries.
lot = []
for i in range(1001):
    for j in reversed(range(333)):
        for k in range(3):
            lot.append((i, 'x', j))

# timeit Results for n = 10
brute_force = 6.55s
itertools = 2.07s
# clearly the itertools solution provided by mhyfritz is much faster.
```

In case anyone is curious, here is a trace of how his code works.

```
+ Outer loop - x, g1
| a [('a', 'x1', 10), ('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9), ('a', 'x4', 8), ('a', 'x5', 8), ('a', 'x6', 7)]
+-- Inner loop - y, g2
  |- 10 [('a', 'x1', 10)]
  |- 9 [('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9)]
  |- 8 [('a', 'x4', 8), ('a', 'x5', 8)]
+ Outer loop - x, g1
| b [('b', 'x1', 10), ('b', 'x2', 9), ('b', 'x3', 8), ('b', 'x4', 7), ('b', 'x5', 6), ('b', 'x6', 5)]
+-- Inner loop - y, g2
  |- 10 [('b', 'x1', 10)]
  |- 9 [('b', 'x2', 9)]
  |- 8 [('b', 'x3', 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea, make a dict with the value you want to sort by as the key and a list of the tuples that have that value as the values.

Then sort the items of the dict by the keys, get the items from the top, extract their values and join them.

Quick, ugly code:

```
>>> sum(
        map(lambda x: x[1],
            sorted(dict([(x[2], filter(lambda y: y[2] == x[2], lot))
                for x in lot]).items(),
                reverse=True)[:3]),
    [])

7: [('a', 'x1', 10),
 ('b', 'x1', 10),
 ('a', 'x2', 9),
 ('a', 'x3', 9),
 ('b', 'x2', 9),
 ('a', 'x4', 8),
 ('a', 'x5', 8),
 ('b', 'x3', 8)]
```

Just to give you some ideas, hope it helps. If you need some clarification ask in the comments

Answer (score 0):

How's about this? It doesn't *exactly* return your desired result, since it reverse-sorts on `y`.

```
# split lot by first element of values
lots = defaultdict(list)
for x, y, z in lot:
    lots[x].append((y, z))

ans = []
for x, l in lots.iteritems():
    # find top-3 unique values
    top = nlargest(3, set(z for (y, z) in l))
    ans += [(x, y, z) for (z, y) in sorted([(z, y) for (y, z) in l
                                                   if z in top],
                                           reverse=True)]

print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import *

categories = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: set()))
for t in myTuples:
    cat1,cat2,val = t
    categories[cat1][val].add(t)

def onlyTopThreeKeys(d):
    keys = sorted(d.keys())[-3:]
    return {k:d[k] for k in keys}

print( {cat1:onlyTopThreeKeys(sets) for cat1,sets in categories.items()} )
```

Result:

```
{'a': {8: {('a', 'x5', 8), ('a', 'x4', 8)},
       9: {('a', 'x3', 9), ('a', 'x2', 9)},
       10: {('a', 'x1', 10)}},
 'b': {8: {('b', 'x3', 8)}, 
       9: {('b', 'x2', 9)}, 
       10: {('b', 'x1', 10)}}}
```

---

**flat list**: I did the method above because it gives you more information. To just get a flat list, use closures to emit results with `onlyTopThreeKeys`:

```
from collections import *

def topTiedThreeInEachCategory(tuples):
    categories = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: set()))
    for t in myTuples:
        cat1,cat2,val = t
        categories[cat1][val].add(t)

    reap = set()

    def sowTopThreeKeys(d):
        keys = sorted(d.keys())[-3:]
        for k in keys:
            for x in d[k]:
                reap.add(x)
    for sets in categories.values():
        sowTopThreeKeys(sets)

    return reap
```

Result:

```
>>> topTiedThreeInEachCategory(myTuples)
{('b', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x1', 10), ('b', 'x3', 8), ('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x4', 8), ('a', 'x3', 9), ('a', 'x5', 8), ('b', 'x1', 10)}
```

---

You can also use `itertools.groupby` if your input is guaranteed to be sorted as in your sample input, but this will cause your code to break if the sorting ever changes.

Comment: wouldn't this fail to extract both of there entries:  `('a', 'x2', 9), ('a', 'x3', 9)` ?

Comment: @Toader: this is why I had already provided sample output, you can look for yourself

Comment: now it works because of this: `categories[cat1][val].add(t)`. When I commented it was `categories[cat1][val] = t` :)

Comment: @Toader: oh oops, my apologies, I didn't realize your comment was from 20min ago. =)